# Can any pair of operators $(a,b)$ that has the same commutation relation as the ladder operators $([a,b]=1)$ be seen as ladder operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

In other words, can we find some Hilbert basis such that one of them has the form

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Pick e.g. $a=q$ as position and $b=p/i\hbar$ as momentum. Then the commutator is also $[a,b]=1$, but $b\neq a^{\dagger}$.